# Mors Alphabet Segmentation Fault

Tags: c

My code doesn't adding second node to tree. It gives me SIGSEGV fault when i'm adding the second node.I think its about strcmp function but when i'm trying to understand how it works properly at the very bottom of main func it returns -1 so i've wrote it like this.And most of my variables named Turkish so here are the translations of them to make you understand more easily
dugum=node,kok=root;sol=left;sag=right;anne=mother

```
// C program to demonstrate insert operation in binary search tree
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct tree {
  char *harf;
  char *morskodu;
  struct tree *left;
  struct tree *right;
} agac;

agac *kok = NULL;

void ekle(char *harf, char *morskodu) {
  if (kok == NULL) {
    kok = (agac *)malloc(sizeof(agac));
    kok->harf = harf;
    kok->morskodu = morskodu;
    kok->left = NULL;
    kok->right= NULL;
  } else {
    agac *yeni = (agac *)malloc(sizeof(agac));
    yeni->harf = harf;
    yeni->morskodu = morskodu;
    yeni->left = NULL;
    yeni->right = NULL;
    agac *dugum = kok, *anne;
    while (dugum != NULL) {
      anne = dugum;
      if (harf <= dugum->harf)
        dugum = dugum->left;
      else
        dugum = dugum->right;
    }
    if (harf <= dugum->harf)
      anne->left = yeni;
    else
      anne->right = yeni;
  }
}

void dolas(agac *dugum) {
  if (dugum != NULL) {
    printf(" %s ", dugum->harf);
    dolas(dugum->left);
    dolas(dugum->right);
  }
}

void main() {
  ekle("a", "-");
  ekle("b", "-.");
  dolas(kok);

  int x = strcmp("A", "B");
  printf("%d", x);
}
```

Comment: You're accessing memory your program doesn't own. If you want to know more you'll have to post the code!

Comment: It would be easier to read if you do a quick search & replace instead of providing translations (and indent the code).

Comment: Sorry that was my first entry so i couldnt get how to share code but i think now i get it

Comment: With some limited success, it is possible to paste C code into Google translate and get something back that is close [it may need a bit of tweaking].

Comment: true this looks like obfuscated code. Harder to figure out the bugs...

Comment: This is not how you compare strings: `if (harf <= dugum->harf)`.  This compares the addresses of memory locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to dereference a NULL pointer.

```
while (dugum != NULL) {
  anne = dugum;
  if (harf <= dugum->harf)
    dugum = dugum->sol;
  else
    dugum = dugum->sag;
}
```

This loop ends when `dugum` is NULL.
Directly after you try to access `dugum->harf`:

```
 if (harf <= dugum->harf)
```

This leads to undefined behavior.

Also note that this comparisons compare the pointers to string literals, and is therefore also undefined behavior. To compare two C strings you should use `strcmp`.

Comment: Thank you for million times :)